# Spoofing the details of a CPU

Tags: memory, security, cpu, spoofing

We usually see the details of a CPU by using the command "lscpu" in Ubuntu. The information comes as such in the picture below.

[Original LSCPU Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL5pa.png)

Is there any tool or way to spoof this information? For example I want to show that my machine has 4 GB RAM where actually it has 16 GB RAM. And I want to show my machine has Intel i3 processor whereas it actually has Intel i5 processor.

Is there any way to do this?

Also, on another note, is there any similar technique to spoof cpu information inside a docker container?

Thanks in advance

Note: There is a technique which was suggested by someone else. It is  `lscpu > SpoofedOutput`  and then alias `lscpu` to `cat SpoofedOutput`
This works only on the same terminal where it has been aliased and not in other terminals. I wanted it in a much more permanent way such that it will show the spoofed output until I restart the PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it permanent, you could define the alias you mentioned in a system wide file such as `/etc/environment` (depending on your distro).